# Magento product details page not loading after search result

Tags: product, catalogsearch, advanced-search

In my magento website, whenever i am trying to view the product details page from search result (means product list is generated from the search query) its not loading the product details page properly. After the breadcrumbs its not displaying anything.The sample url is given below.

https://www.example.com/index.php/test.html

And the breadcrumbs is displaying like Home/test.html

If I go the category page and view the same particular product then it shows perfectly with below url.

https://www.example.com/index.php/category1/test.html  and breadcrumbs looks like Home/category1/test.html.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the breadcrumbs is not to care about here. It seems there is some php or javascript error, which terminates further execution. Check for any javascript errors first and then check for php errors. I too had a similar problem 8 months back and it was a php variable error (variable was null and thus stopped further execution).

Comment: thanks for quick response. I would like to mention  that if i go to the same product detail page from category listing then its displaying properly but from the search result page, its not displaying the  product detail page.For you information i have a magento store with 30k products and i have used a theme which have functionality to displaying pre/next product in details page.I doubt the problem is for pre/next functionality which is depends on search result.

Comment: is it a free theme or paid one? if it's free tell me what theme i can check it for u...

Comment: @Shathish  thanks for your support. I just removed the functionality of prev/next from my product details page.It works fine. Actually it takes lot of time to execute that's why script is stopped after some time and some time a fatal error shows that "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted "

Comment: ai8! glad u got it working now, try to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was on my catalog/product/view page. I have a magento store with 30k products and I have used a theme which have functionality to displaying Pre/Next product in details page for this details page was taking lot of time to execute. I have just removed the pre/next functionality from catalog/product/view page and it works fine.I have also truncated the core_url_rewrite table and Reindex Catalog URL Rewrites.